# Redirect output of mongo query to a csv file changes the date format

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to export output of mongo query to csv file. My code is like this

*test.js*:

```js
db.<dbname>.find().forEach(function(d){print(d._id.valueOf()+","+d.date);});
```

then I am passing this file to my script,

```
mongo <mongoDB> test.js > test.csv
```

i am getting the date files as **Mon Jul 30 2018 15:11:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)** but I want the date field to export exactly like mongoDB format like **2018-07-30T15:11:25.862+00:00**

Comment: Exporting the query output in JSON might help. JSON keeps the values and data types as is in the data. I have tried exporting data fields with `null` values which were exported as "null" string in CSV, while in JSON the data was kept as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

That format you are looking for is called ISO-8601.

MongoDB stores dates as a 64-bit integers, so what is actually stored, and passed back to the client, for that date is `1532963485000`

The javascript `print` function in the mongo shell uses the `toString()` method of each object, for ISODate that returns the string you saw.

Mongo shell support tab-completion, so you can find the methods available for an ISODate object like:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> var dt = new Date(1532963485000);
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> dt.   <-- Press tab here
dt.constructor            dt.getMonth(              dt.getUTCHours(           dt.propertyIsEnumerable(  dt.setSeconds(            dt.setUTCMonth(           dt.toLocaleString(
dt.getDate(               dt.getSeconds(            dt.getUTCMilliseconds(    dt.setDate(               dt.setTime(               dt.setUTCSeconds(         dt.toLocaleTimeString(
dt.getDay(                dt.getTime(               dt.getUTCMinutes(         dt.setFullYear(           dt.setUTCDate(            dt.setYear(               dt.toString(
dt.getFullYear(           dt.getTimezoneOffset(     dt.getUTCMonth(           dt.setHours(              dt.setUTCFullYear(        dt.toDateString(          dt.toTimeString(
dt.getHours(              dt.getUTCDate(            dt.getUTCSeconds(         dt.setMilliseconds(       dt.setUTCHours(           dt.toGMTString(           dt.toUTCString(
dt.getMilliseconds(       dt.getUTCDay(             dt.getYear(               dt.setMinutes(            dt.setUTCMilliseconds(    dt.toISOString(           dt.tojson(
dt.getMinutes(            dt.getUTCFullYear(        dt.hasOwnProperty(        dt.setMonth(              dt.setUTCMinutes(         dt.toLocaleDateString(    dt.valueOf(
```

I your case, you probably want to use

```
d.date.toISOString()
```